# How to load a custom table view cell in cell for row at indexpath delegate in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
import UIKit

class NewOrdersViewControllers: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    var items = []
    @IBOutlet var tableView:UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblRestaurantNames: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: UIButton!

    var cellIdentifier = "cell"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "vwTblCell", bundle: nil)

        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.delegate = self

        tableView.dataSource = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func mapPush(sender: AnyObject) {

        let mapVC = MapViewController()

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mapVC, animated: true)
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

//            let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier)! as! UITableViewCell
//
//            cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row] as! String
//
//            cell.RestaurantLbl.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
//
//            cell.lblrest.text = items[indexPath.row] as! String

        var cell:TblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TblCell

        cell.lblRestaurantName.text = items[indexPath.row] as! String

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 100
    }
```

Comment: What issue you are facing in your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let identifier = "Custom"

        var cell: CustomCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? CustomCel  

          if cell == nil {
                tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
               cell =tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? CustomCell
            }
          return cell
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
         let cell:TblCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TblCell

         cell.lblRestaurantName.text = items[indexPath.row] as! String

        return cell;

   }
```